# PHP thinks there are 2 months between Apr 1st and Jul1st

Tags: datediff, php-5.5

PHP 5.5.1.14:

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2014-04-01 00:00");
$d2 = new DateTime("2014-07-01 00:00");
$d3 = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $d3->m . " months, " . $d3->d . " days";
```

returns

> 2 months, 30 days

Is there a way to reliably get the intuitive result 3 months? (Is this a bug or not?)
BTW, when using May1st and Aug 1st, it gives the expected result of 3 months...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time doesn't matter and you need just months diff, you can take second date with '23:59' time.

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2014-04-01 00:00");
$d2 = new DateTime("2014-07-01 23:59");
$d3 = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $d3->m . " months"
```

returns

```
3 months
```

And all other date pairs since 2014-01-01 - 2014-04-01 until 2014-12-01 - 2015-03-01 will return `3 months`